# How to write a MySQL before insert trigger to insert data in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I need to create a trigger for when I insert data in the first table to be able to insert in the second some data related to the first one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test1
ON Telegramas
BEFORE INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dispositivos SET Dispositivos.GrupoOrigen = Telegramas.GrupoOrigen;
  END;
```

I have created that but there is a syntax error that I can not see. Some help? or another way to make the relationship easier?

Comment: can you share the syntax error with us?

Comment: Error

consulta SQL:

CREATE TRIGGER telegramas.test1 ON TelegramasBEFORE INSERT AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Dispositivos
SET Dispositivos.GrupoOrigen = Telegramas.GrupoOrigen;

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON Telegramas
BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Dispositivos SET Dispo' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the delimiter, like this :

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER test1

 [...]
END |
delimiter ;
```

But there is a problem in your trigger :

```
 delimiter |
    CREATE TRIGGER test1  BEFORE INSERT ON Telegramas
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Dispositivos SET GrupoOrigen = NEW.GrupoOrigen;
    END |
 delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked correctly but when I insert two identical data in the main table, I only insert one that is not repeated but with the trigger in table 2 it inserts the two instead of just one. @jean-doux